# Negative margin does not render correctly

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I have a problem with Internet Explorer 6 and 7. The Browser is not rendering my code right when I use a negative margin. I guess it doesn't work. This code is a menu bar.

Here is the CSS:

```
#navbar ul { 
        margin: 0; 
        padding: 5px; 
        list-style-type: none; 
        text-align: center; 
        background-color: #000; 
        } 

#navbar ul li {  
        display: inline; 
        } 

#navbar ul li a { 
        text-decoration: none; 
        padding: .2em 1em; 
        color: #fff; 
        background-color: #000; 
        } 

#navbar ul li a:hover { 
        color: #000; 
        background-color: #fff; 
        }
```

And in the body of the HTML:

```
<div id="navbar"> 
  <ul> 
        <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">test</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">test</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
  </ul> 
</div>
```

I set the margin at 0, so the menubar can go to the top. So I tried a negative number. But that doesn't work in Internet Explorer. Any ideas?

Comment: MAAn! I even don't think of those old creepy browsers while creating the website look for only IE9+.

Comment: For IE8, it's always important to check the <DOCTYPE> and make sure it's not running in some compatibility mode.  You can verify this with the F12 tools..